# How do I clean up my react code by creating a seperate css grid component that is also mobile friendly?

Tags: reactjs, mobile, grid, css-grid

I am hoping to make a grid component out of this that is also mobile friendly. I am hoping to take this entire chunk of code out of app.js and put it into one component file. I am hoping to do this without a seperate css file.

```
const GridLayout = styled.div`
 height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "nav nav nav"
    "asideLeft main asideRight"
    "leftFooter footer rightFooter";
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr 8fr 1fr auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr 2fr auto 1fr;
`;

const Nav = styled.nav`
      grid-area: nav;
      font-size: calc(20px + 0.25em);
      border-right: 10px solid;
    `;

const AsideLeft = styled.aside`
  grid-area: asideLeft;

  transform: rotate(20deg);
  border-bottom: 25px solid;
  align-self: start;
`;
const AsideRight = styled.aside`
  grid-area: asideRight;
  font-weight: bolder;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
  border-right: 18px solid;
  justify-content: end;
`;
const Main = styled.main`
  border-top: 15px solid;
  grid-area: main;
`;
const Footer = styled.footer`
  border-top: 20px solid;
  grid-area: footer;
  font-size: calc(10px + 0.25em);
  border-bottom: 40px solid;
`;
```

Thanks for the help! Its driving me craaazy!

Answer (score 1):

You could start by just using the existing css and adding a media query to your `GridLayout` component.

```
const GridLayout = styled.div`
 height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "nav nav nav"
    "asideLeft main asideRight"
    "leftFooter footer rightFooter";
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr 8fr 1fr auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr 2fr auto 1fr;

@media screen and (max-width: /*some size here*/) {
  //some styling here
}
`;
```

for example to remove *asideRight* on screens 700px or less...

```
const GridLayout = styled.div`
 height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "nav nav nav"
    "asideLeft main asideRight"
    "leftFooter footer rightFooter";
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  grid-template-areas:
    "nav nav nav"
    "asideLeft main main"
    "leftFooter footer rightFooter";
}
`;
```

*note that I did change some of the original styled properties

Comment: Tried this:@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-areas:
      "nav nav nav"
      "asideLeft"
      "main"
      "asideRight"
      "leftFooter"
      "footer"
      "rightFooter";
  }
}

Comment: I'm sorry, not sure what you meant with the last comment @MyBrainHurts

Comment: I added that media code where you said but it still seems to be not working  '@media (max-width: 700px) { .grid { grid-template-areas: "nav nav nav" "asideLeft" "main" "asideRight" "leftFooter" "footer" "rightFooter"; } }'

Comment: I noticed _.grid_ in your comment, that is not needed. And in the media query, you would need to change one of the grid or style properties to see the change. Also in your code did you mean `grid-auto-rows` or `grid-template-rows`?

Comment: Still a jangle screen when I make it the minumum on desktop...here is with a different newer code: `@media (max-width: 700px) { .grid { grid-template-areas: "nav nav nav" "asideLeft" "main" "asideRight" "leftFooter" "footer" "rightFooter"; } }`

Comment: Like I mentioned before you dont need the _.grid_ in there. From your comment `@media (max-width: 700px) { .grid { grid-template-areas: "nav nav nav" "asideLeft" "main" "asideRight" "leftFooter" "footer" "rightFooter"; } }` should be `@media (max-width: 700px) { grid-template-areas: "nav nav nav" "asideLeft" "main" "asideRight" "leftFooter" "footer" "rightFooter"; }` I added a similar example in my answer.

Comment: Hmmm - tried this noticing more of change but still a lot of wonky behaviour `@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    grid-template-areas:
      "nav"
      "nav"
      "nav"
      "asideLeft"
      "main"
      "asideRight"
      "leftFooter"
      "footer"
      "rightFooter";
  }`

Comment: I took you original styled-components and loaded them as-is into a code sandbox and I'm scratching my head as to how it's supposed to look...

Comment: Check out www.code.adamaslan.com from desktop. That's how it is supposed to look. So mobile would have all the same features just stacked vertically.

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how to better word this question to get others involved?